# laravel eloquent: Get all groups for a member

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

```
user: id,name
```

`group:  id,name,parent_id`  made with [this](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset))  // this is a nested category

```
members: id,user_id,group_id,admin
```

and `group_member: group_id,member_id`
I want get all groups (include sub groups) for a member. Is it possible do it via laravel?

Group Modal:

```
  public function parent()
  {
    $parent =  $this->belongsTo('App\Group',  'parent_id');
    return $parent;
  }

  public function children()
  {
    $children = $this->hasMany('App\Group',  'parent_id');
    //$children->wherePublish(1);
    return $children;
  }



  public function members()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(Member::class);
  }

  public function member()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Member::class);
  }
```

And Member model:

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
}

public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
}
```

And user model:

```
public function members()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Member::class);
}
```

I want something like this (to return all related groups):

```
auth()->user()->members()->groups()->get();
```

I got this error:

> "Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::groups()"

Answer (score 0):

Please use this below query:

```
 App/User::where('id',auth()->user()->id)->with('members.groups')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks.But it return users. I want groups.